# Speeding up Java Code

Tags: java, performance, while-loop, try-catch

I am having a problem with the speed of my code. I am connected to 2 WiFi modules and getting real time data from the status.xml. Unfortunately it has a delay of 2-3 seconds.I never had to deal with code speed up, so that is why I need help.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    URL temp;
    URL move;
    String inputLine1 = null,inputLine2 = null;
    gui.setVisible(true);
    BufferedReader in1 = null, in2;
    try{
        temp = new URL("http://192.168.0.25/status.xml");
        move = new URL("http://192.168.0.26/status.xml");

        while(true) {
            in1 = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(temp.openStream()));
            in2 = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(move.openStream()));  

            while ((inputLine1 = in1.readLine()) != null) {
                if (inputLine1.contains("<adctemp>") ) {
                    Temperature = inputLine1;
                    Temperature = Temperature.replaceFirst("<adctemp>", "").replaceAll("</adctemp>", "");
                }
            }

            while ((inputLine2 = in2.readLine()) != null) {
                if(inputLine2.contains("<led2>")) {
                    Motion = inputLine2;
                    Motion = Motion.replaceFirst("<led2>", "").replaceAll("</led2>","");
                    if(Motion.contains("0")) {
                        Movement = 0;
                    }
                    else  {
                        Movement = 1;
                    }

                } 
            }

            Thread.run();
        }
    }catch(IOException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    } 
}
```

Comment: I'd start of by using an XML parser to parse XML...

Comment: Add some log statements to see where the time is lost.

Comment: Can you give me an example for using logs?

Comment: @JonSkeet using an XML parser is probably a good idea in general, but maybe he only needs to do minimal parsing like shown in this code. I doubt if that will improve performance in such case.

Comment: @traveh: it may not fix performance in itself, but it's easier to investigate performance issues with clean code to start with :)

Comment: no argument there... :)

Comment: I only need to simple numbers from this xml, that looks like this:


     
     <response>
   <scan>0</scan>
 <ver>310c</ver>
 <count>1</count>
 <ssid>MCHP_G_3f5b</ssid>
 
 <bss>
  <valid>0</valid>
  <name>0</name>
  <privacy>0</privacy>
  <wlan>SoftAP (BSS)</wlan>
  <strength>0</strength>
 </bss>

 <led0>0</led0>
 <led1>0</led1>
 <led2>0</led2>
 <btn0>up</btn0>
 <adctemp>26</adctemp>
 </response>

Answer (score 0):

Network speed is hardware  and that will govern how much performance you can get. But as far as threading is concerned you can create two threads and read async in that. Currently its happening in serial order.

Comment: It is not a hardware problem, that is for sure. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Check if the problem is the speed of your code or the speed of the wifi end point.

If the problem is on the wifi end point you can't do nothing in your code.

To check your code use a mock of the wifi end part reading data from memory or from file (not from network).

If the problems remains you can improve your code. Don't operate on it before you are sure that the bottleneck is your code.

**Note:** There is a `Thread.run()` in your code. What was your idea for the purpose of this line?

Comment: I am refreshing the status.xml in my browser, and I can see the changes, but i can't see them on my GUI only after couple of seconds. I tried with System.out.println too, the same thing happends. That Line makes the connection to the GUI.

Answer (score 0):

If the input from the two streams doesn't have to be run serially, one major optimization you can do is to do the reading from the two input streams in parallel.

Simply put the code that reads the input from each stream in a separate class and run it in a separate thread, then you can use `join()` to make sure both are finished.

However, since thread creation and destruction is relatively costly, an even better optimization would be to keep the threads going and communicate between them with thread synchronization. The performance improvement from this depends on how many times the inner while statements are reached, so it would be premature optimization to write that at the start.

Answer (score -1):

As i do not see any relationship between the processing of both WiFi module data, i suggest you to create 2 threads and hence each thread will try to process the corresponding module in parallel and hence increase in performance,

```
Thread th1 = new Thread() {
    public void run() {
        while(true) {
            BufferedReader in1 = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(temp.openStream()));
            while ((inputLine1 = in1.readLine()) != null) {
                if (inputLine1.contains("<adctemp>") ) 
                {
                    Temperature = inputLine1;
                    Temperature = Temperature.replaceFirst("<adctemp>", "").replaceAll("</adctemp>", "");

                }
            }
        }
    }
};

Thread th2 = new Thread() {
    public void run() {
        while(true) {
            BufferedReader in2 = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(move.openStream()));
            while ((inputLine2 = in2.readLine()) != null) {
                if(inputLine2.contains("<led2>"))
                {
                    Motion = inputLine2;
                    Motion = Motion.replaceFirst("<led2>", "").replaceAll("</led2>","");
                    if(Motion.contains("0"))
                    {Movement = 0;}
                    else 
                    {Movement = 1;}
                } 
            }
        }
    }
};

th1.start();
th2.start();
```

Comment: Inadequate. Obviously he uses the results from the threads or the program would be just doing nothing... and it is done *after* both reads have finished. The way you suggested this he will have synchronization issues.

Comment: hmm... its obvious that one needs to handle synchronization issues when dealing with multiple threads. What i have shown is a way to speed up the process by dividing the work in multiple threads.

Comment: I know that - I suggested the same thing 5 minutes before you, but the code suggestion you gave is almost guaranteed to be flawed unless there is absolutely no relation between the input from the separate streams, which I doubt is true.